# In SharePoint 2013, in the Lists feature how can I add a date and timestamp to an attachment?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list-form, attachments, timestamp

First, let me say I am a complete novice regarding SharePoint 2013. The issue I am having is for Lists.  When I open a Form to add data to a List, I am able to upload attachments to that form. Ideally, I would like to know when each attachment was uploaded by having a date/time stamp associated with each attachment. We are using this List as a ticketing system for application bugs and it would be helpful to our developers and testers if they knew how recent and in which order the supporting document attachments came in.

Can someone help with this?  And please, ELI5 (explain like I'm five).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, using this approach won't work (I don't know a way to do that using the list attachment.

What I would suggest you to do (I am trying ELI5 as much as I can) is to create a document library to save the attachments in and link it to your list using a lookup column. Then you can join the 2 lists together to show documents attached to a list item.

You can find good information on how to link 2 lists together here:
https://davidlozzi.com/2012/08/02/creating-an-item-detail-dashboard-view-of-your-joined-lists-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Ok, I understand.  Definitely not ideal.  Maybe I'll have to try a file naming convention to get around this.  Thanks for the quick response!